# Delete duplicate records without primary key in table in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Need to delete duplicates from a table, but table does not have any primary key.

```
tried with Row_number,rowid but these function is not available in redshift.
```

can someone help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Row_Number function exists in Redshift , However if you are trying to delete using the CTE it won't work and will give you an error 'CTE does not exist'.

Also , if you try using the below CTE posted by -'user18098820'
it will delete all the duplicate records present in the table and will not retain any specific records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DISTINCT** in a **SELECT** to create a new table without duplicates.

```
begin;
create table table_name_new as select distinct * from table_name;
alter table table_name rename to table_name_old;
alter table table_name_new rename to table_name;
drop table table_name_old;
commit;
```

**NB** `ROW_NUMBER()` does exist in Redshift.
You could use the following syntax to delete duplicates. Replace identity columns with the columns which define uniqueness in your table.
Run the query with `SELECT * FROM cte` in the place of `DELETE FROM cte` first to check what will be deleted.

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY identiy_columns)
FROM table_name)
DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE ROW_NUMBER > 1;
```

Comment: Assume I do not have create/alter/drop privileges for higher env

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this should work, I will check & accept the answer

Comment: For select this query is working but for delete it's giving error , that <cte> table doe not exist

Comment: I guess you will have to ask a person with the needed privileges to create/alter/drop to run your script prepared according to the first method.

Answer (score 0):

We have encountered the same issue where we don't have any primary key columns in our table.

Basically, In Amazon Redshift, the effective approaches to delete duplicate records and retain unique records is to use a temporary table. The process involves creating a temporary table to store the distinct records, deleting the existing data from the main table, and then inserting the unique records from the temporary table back into the main table.

Steps:

1. Create a temp_table

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM main_table;
```

2. Delete the existing data from the main table:

```sql
DELETE FROM main_table;
```

3. Insert the unique records from the temporary table into the main table:

```sql
INSERT INTO main_table
SELECT * FROM temp_table;
```

drop the temporary table:

Comment: I would like to highlight - i've checked  the above queries posted by other users. It will delete all the records present in the table which you don't want.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler2P for the edit. I'll learn to post with the correct formatting :)